# Best practice for dealing with link rot?

Tags: discussion

I was editing [an old answer](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/a/10124/2280) today to add some information, and discovered that almost all of my meticulously chosen links now lead nowhere. Some of this seems to be due to sites taking old content offline, and some of it due to sites redesigning and breaking the paths to old content.

Whatever the case, my answer referenced some quite old articles that are now no longer available anywhere. What should I do about it? I've come up with a couple of ideas:

- (as a minimum) Tag the dead links somehow so that people know they have been recognised as dead? Is it woth bothering?
- Try to find the original content on the Wayback machine and link to it there (The wayback machine does not have any versions of these pages with content - they have archived the 404 page)
- Delete the dead links
- Find new/different links to similar content (not possible in many instances).

Comment: Prevention is worth a pound of cure: upvote the answers that quote (or at a minimum summarise) the contents of the key sites they link to. If an answer doesn't, edit it so it does.

Comment: Same problem here a few days ago (youtube vid no longer available): http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/4317/are-there-airborne-poop-particles-flying-around-bathrooms/4325#4325

Comment: relatedly, moderators see a link rot queue.

Comment: As a side note, you can (at time of original writing) try to get the Wayback machine to save a page by using the 'save a page now' box at [Wayback](https://archive.org/web/web.php). I rather assume that won't override a robots.txt, but if it's just something they hadn't gotten to yet, it might help get the link target saved.